Bar chart plot shows linearly increasing data
Using Python plotly, the charted data shows linearly increasing data, but is not correct.
Also, the first data point (i.e. 5585) is rendered as empty bar.
How do I fix these?
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()

x = df_quaterly_results.index 
y = df_quaterly_results[df_quaterly_results.columns[0]]  # Sales Columns

trace_name = 'QoQ Sales'

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y, name=trace_name))

plot_title = 'QoQ Sales'

fig.update_layout(
        title=plot_title,
        xaxis_title='Quarter',
        yaxis_title='Rupees in Cr.')

# pyo.plot(fig, filename="temp-plot.html")
fig.show()


Sample Dataframe:



Quarter
Sales




Jun 2021
5585


Sep 2021
7096


Dec 2021
8527


Mar 2022
7893


Jun 2022
8607


Sep 2022
8458



Note: The column Quarter is dataframe index here.

The issue suggests that the 'Sales' column in your dataframe contains strings, in which case Plotly uses a categorical axis.
You just need to convert df_quaterly_results['Sales'] or at least y to the proper type, eg.
y = df_quaterly_results['Sales'].astype(int)

Sample dataframe plotted with categorical axis :

Sample dataframe plotted with numerical axis :


Ah yes Indeed its object ! I missed to check the df.info(). Thanks !

You're reading the wrong column for sales.
Just access the columns by name, it looks cleaner and solves the problem
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Quarter': ['Jun 2021', 'Sep 2021', 'Dec 2021', 'Mar 2022', 'Jun 2022', 'Sep 2022'],
    'Sales': [5585, 7096, 8527, 7893, 8607, 8458]
}

df_quaterly_results = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = go.Figure()

x = df_quaterly_results['Quarter'] 
y = df_quaterly_results['Sales']

trace_name = 'QoQ Sales'

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y, name=trace_name))

plot_title = 'QoQ Sales'

fig.update_layout(
        title=plot_title,
        xaxis_title='Quarter',
        yaxis_title='Rupees in Cr.')

fig.show()


Ok, this works, but the Quarter is the index of the dataframe here.

Ok. But can you clarify what is wrong or deficient about the graph that gets plotted with this approach? How is Quarter being the index affecting anything here?

Is there a way to plot with index ?

You need to set the index first and then assign axis.
Add the below, before setting x,
df_quaterly_results.set_index('Quarterly Results', inplace=True)

Complete code in your question, with the index set logic,
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

fig = go.Figure()

data = {
    'Quarterly Results': ['Jun 2021', 'Sep 2021', 'Dec 2021', 'Mar 2022', 'Jun 2022', 'Sep 2022'],
    'Sales': [5585, 7096, 8527, 7893, 8607, 8458]
}
df_quaterly_results = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_quaterly_results.set_index('Quarterly Results', inplace=True)

x = df_quaterly_results.index
y = df_quaterly_results[df_quaterly_results.columns[0]]  # Sales Columns

trace_name = 'QoQ Sales'

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=y, name=trace_name))

plot_title = 'QoQ Sales'

fig.update_layout(
        title=plot_title,
        xaxis_title='Quarter',
        yaxis_title='Rupees in Cr.')

# pyo.plot(fig, filename="temp-plot.html")
fig.show()


